# Solution-verification of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3}{1 \cdot 3+3\cdot5+\cdots+(2n-1)(2n+1)}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I solved this limit and got the solution $\frac{3}{4}$. I tryed checking on WolframAlpha, but when generating the presentation of the expression it shows $\lim{n\to n}$ instead of $\lim{n \to \infty}$ and tells me that the limit diverges. So I'm unsure whether it diverges because of the misinterpretation of the problem or the limit truly is diverging.

EDIT: Fellow colleague Acheca provided the solution in the comments to the WolframAlpha problem, [here it is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einf+n%5E3%2F%28sum+from+i%3D0+to+n-1+of+%282*i%2B1%29*%282*i%2B3%29%29), which btw answers my question with a yes.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3}{1 \cdot 3+3\cdot5+\cdots+(2n-1)(2n+1)}\right)$$

I applied the Stolz-Cesaro theorem and eventually (after the initial steps) got

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^3-n^3}{1 \cdot 3+3\cdot5+\cdots+(2n-1)(2n+1)-(1 \cdot 3+3\cdot5+\cdots+(2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+1)(2n+3))}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n^2+3n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Is the result correct ?

Thanks in advance

P.S.
Should I delete these kinds of questions if the answer to them is a simple yes, since they don't provide much information and may not be of great use to anyone except me ?

Comment: To answer your P.S., no, you should not delete this. Imagine if someone had the same question but this answer existed, then we have all done well for the community by mitigating duplicates! Asking if a solution is valid is equivalent to answering a question :)

Comment: It is correct. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einf+n%5E3%2F%28sum+from+i%3D0+to+n-1+of+%282*i%2B1%29*%282*i%2B3%29%29) is the proper way of writing in Wolfram Alpha so you get the limits correctly, by the way

Comment: @ACheca Many thanks for the clarification and the WolframAlpha issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answer is correct but Cesaro-Stolz isn't really necessary since

- $\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(2k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n(4k^2-1) = 4\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}_{=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}} -n$
- $\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(2k+1) \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\sim}\frac 43n^3$

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac 34$.